# Can WPF XAML extensions be used in other projects?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, maui

I am researching [WPF XAML Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-extensions?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0). However, XAML is a language, used in other project types - for example `UWP`, `.NET MAUI` etc., and the extensions don't seem to be tied to `WPF`. Can ***all*** the Markup Extensions mentioned in the link be used in `UWP` and `MAUI` projects, too? Attempting to change the page from `.Net Framework 4.x` to `.NET 6.0` version is unsuccessful, as "the newest product this page is available for is .Net Framework v.4.x".
However, I managed to find equivalent `UWP` pages for the

- [Binding Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension)
- [RelativeSource Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/relativesource-markup-extension)
- [StaticResource Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/staticresource-markup-extension)
- [ThemeResource Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension)

I assume only these coinciding extensions can be used in `UWP` and that all other unmentioned extensions cannot. The same extensions appear to be available in [MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/markup-extensions/consume?view=net-maui-7.0). Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, I'll mention that the fact that `WPF XAML Extensions` are not supported in .Net 6 implies that they can't be used with Maui. (Or any project that is targetting .Net 6).

Comment: My confusion was caused by the wrong impression that the extensions are only a feature of XAML and not of the project type or the platform. The poor translation of articles on .Net Framework and .NET on my native language also contributed negatively. I know the difference now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
In WPF, markup extensions are derived from `System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension`.
In UWP - from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.MarkupExtension`.
In MAUI - this is any type that implements the `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.IMarkupExtension` interface.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve my question?

Comment: Also, I have a side question. Can XAML Extensions be interpreted as syntax sugar for embedding property objects (if I can coin such a term :-D) into other objects, i.e
`<object property="{Binding ...}" ...>` instead of `<object ...><Binding .../></object>` or this is valid only for `Binding`. I suspect it's a dumb question but I have never worked with XAML and WPF so far.

Comment: @DanielHalachev , A markup extension is needed when, when assigning a value, you need to perform some kind of data processing. In the simplest case, this can simply be getting some value. I use this very often when creating converters. Example in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74378365/13349759

Comment: Yes, it's sugar. But XAML, in general, is also sugar. Therefore, it is incorrect to give such an assessment only to the markup extension.

Comment: It is difficult for me to explain in detail in English. I speak Russian. Therefore, I may have written something inaccurately.

Comment: You explained it in a very understandable way. Thank you, it's all clear now. Спасибо :-)